# Роллета есть такое слово?

Tags: число

В предложении: «Злоумышленник повредил роллетУ и забрался в магазин». Роллеты - множественное число, а единственное: роллет или роллета?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Такие слова, как *ролставни* (*роллставни*), *ролеты* (*роллеты*), *жалюзи*, *ставни*, *ворота* не имеют формы единственного числа и употребляются только во множественном.

Comment: тогда «Злоумышленник повредил роллетЫ и...»?

Comment: Сеть пестрит ролеттами, употребляя и ед. число. Ошибкой большой никто не назовёт и такой вариант.